# Блок аккаунта на неделю за "накрутку"? Что это было?

Tags: поддержка, блокировка

Случился весьма странный случай с моим аккаунтом.

Я последним временем(месяца 3-4) не особо активный на SO. А последние 2 недели был вообще за городом и не активный в интернете в принципе(не только на SO).

Но где-то около недели назад мне на имейл прислали сообщуху что мой акк заблокирован за...  накрутку балов. И что мои балы забрали и у меня стало 1 бал.

Заглянув в историю балов я увидел пункт "-165 - учасник был удален".

Это как-то связано с этой "накруткой"?

Кого вообще можно попросить посмотреть что случилось? Имеет ли кто доступ к логам или что-то подобное?

Как вообще уберечься от подобного в будущем? Не оч хочется утратить свои балы и быть в следующий раз безсрочно забаненым то ли по какой-то глупой ошибке то ли по чьей-то "шутке" с простановкой балов всем подряд вопросам/ответам.

Я физически не мог накручивать сидя в "мухосранске" с мобильного. Да и не зачем - у меня и так балов на "модерские права" хватает, которыми я, даже, не пользуюсь...

Comment: Вам же пришло мод сообщение при блокировке? Если у вас есть вопросы по блокировке - просто ответьте на него, не стоит сразу писать пост на мете.

Comment: @PashaPash я расписал в том вопросе что со стороны SO можно сделать что бы подобные вопросы больше не возникали.

Comment: @PashaPash а [тут](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50765671#50765671) не такая же история? (с блокировкой 0xdb на неделю — «Учётная запись временно заблокирована за нарушения при голосовании»)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin причина блокировки та же.

Comment: @PashaPash, у меня в истории репутации, как и у Andrew, тоже есть недавняя запись (от 20 июня) — «-60 баллов: участник был удалён». подозреваю, что во всём этом есть какая-то связь.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не обязательно. Может человек и вправду удалился -- на сколько я помню в StackExchange такая возможность имеется. Но я не в курсе что случается с балами в таком случае. Просто в моем случае это случилось в тот же день когда меня забанили поэтому и подумал что это может быть связанно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin при удалении учётки за накрутку откатываются все ее голоса (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/). Точно так же откатывает голоса от самоудаленных участников до некоторого порога репутации. Они обычно распределены  по многим участникам - у всех снимает по чуть-чуть. У меня тоже -80 прилетело.

Comment: ГОЛОСУЮЩИМ ЗА ПЕРЕОТКРЫТИЕ: не нужно переоткрывать. Ответ я получил в личку по почте -- я уже добился того, чего хотел этим вопросом. Окроме того я и сам считаю этот вопрос дубликатом того вопроса. Спасибо :)